# What's the difference between 'bis heute Abend' and 'bis zum Abend'

Tags: preposition

> (a) Ich bleibe bis heute Abend bei uns.
> (b) Ich bleibe bis zum Abend bei uns.

(a) That's until the evening
(b) is the maximum evening? I don't mind going out before evening?

Comment: Hi kim, I took the liberty to edit the title and to make it english, since you're asking your question in English. It is also allowed to ask your question in German but a mixing of both languages should generally be avoided :)

Comment: Thank you I made a mistake. Sorry

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In (a) you are explicitly specifying **today's** evening (*heute = today*), while in (b) you mean that evening, that makes the most sense when you know the context. Without having this context, I would guess, it's today's evening, but when the context makes another evening more plausible, then it will be this other evening.

Here are two examples:

1. > Ich muss jetzt mal zum Baumarkt, ich bin aber gegen 14:00 Uhr wieder daheim und **bleibe dann bis zum Abend bei uns.**
   > I have to go to the hardware store now, but I'll be back home around 14:00 and then **stay with us until the evening.**

   In this example you also could have said, *"... und bleibe dann bis heute Abend bei uns." = "... and then stay with us until today evening."* It would mean exactly the same in this context.
2. > In zwei Wochen werde ich am Samstag am Vormittag bei Tante Julia sein. Danach fahre ich wieder heim zu uns und **bleibe dann bis zum Abend bei uns.**
   > In two weeks I will be at Aunt Julia's on Saturday morning. After that I will go back home to us and then **stay with us until the evening.**

   In this example *bis zum Abend* does **not** mean today's evening, but the evening of Saturday in two weeks. Saying *"bis heute Abend" = "until today evening"* makes no sense when you talk about the Saturday in two weeks.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer

Answer (score 0):

Heute Abend = This evening
Bis zum Abend = Till the evening

The second phrase does not explicitly tell what evening. In most cases, it means this evening, though.